# Django with nginx static file doesn't load

Tags: python, django, nginx

I ran django server with Debug = True option.

Yesterday, I changed it to Debug = False, and then static file doesn't load.

/etc/nginx/site-enabled/web :

```
server {
    server_name my_domain;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/project/static/;
    }
}
```

settings.py static setting :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

static directory path is not wrong. 
I run server with `python mange.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Try `./manage.py collectstatic` before you run the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must announce to your program the location of static files, so change the urls.py file like this please:

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

```
urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then run following command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```